# Is it good to go to create action from index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, routes

I am creating an app in rails

I have a few buttons in my index view. But I want to execute the `create` action and `destroy` action based on the button on the index page. Is it a good approach doing such things. Or should I always goto `new/destroy` before doing the above operation? Or should I make new actions based on my requirement?

My app is like a task manager
In the index page it displays all the users and the task assigned in a tabular form. A user will be always associated with a task and vice versa.
I should be able to add and delete a task.
And all operation I want is shown in just index page and that's the only page available.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: @RSB: Updated .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the create action does not require further user input, then I see no reason not to go straight to create.

As for example where there is a grid where each cell in the grid contains a link to create and the parameters used in each cell depends on its position in the grid. A calendar month grid being one example, where a click on cell 0,2 will create an item associated with the third day of the first week.

Going straight to destroy is the normal Rails behaviour.